# "aFile.m" is not part of the build phase of any targets in this workspace

Tags: xcode

I'm asking this question again since the other one had an answer that did not work for me.

I'm getting this message when trying to rename a class, along with code sense and color syntax broken.

The file is in the build phase of the target.

I'have tried erasing the derived data to rebuild the index. I can see the index rebuilding but this does not help.

I'm using Xcode 4.2

Comment: Your first sentence seems to indicate this is a repeated question? Can you show a screenshot of the error and also a screenshot of where aFile.m file appears in your target's Build Phase?

Comment: I reverted to a snapshot I had taken earlier that day and all is working. I'm sure it will happen again. Once it does I will update the question with the screenshots. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I found it to be a bug in Xcode 4.1 under OS X 10.7.1 along side with other issues i had. When I reopen my project, the message was gone, refactoring worked as expected and auto-completing worked as well.

Comment: I tried all the suggestions on other related threads with no luck. I had to go back to an earlier snapshot. I haven't had any problems again, but now I do snapshots like crazy.